# Как перевести escapes

Tags: регулярные-выражения, терминология

Примеры:

- character escapes: `\z`
- control-character escapes: `\n`
- Unicode escapes: `\u0020`
- hexadecimal escapes: `\x20`
- octal escape sequences: `\040`

Как правильно перевести?

- экранированные символы: `\z`
- управляющие последовательности: `\n`
- юникодные ________: `\u0020`
- шестнадцатеричные ________: `\x20`
- восьмеричные ________: `\040`

Для первых двух вариантов тоже можно предложить более подходящий перевод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode экранированные последовательности ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting#Unicode_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8))
Шестнадцатеричные экранированные последовательности ([MDN](http://%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/))
Восьмеричные экранированные последовательности (по аналогии)

Этот вариант мне кажется логичнее, чем `экранирующие последовательности` в [PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php), но тем не менее, вот второй вариант (встречается чаще):

Unicode экранирующие последовательности
Шестнадцатеричные экранирующие последовательности
Восьмеричные экранирующие последовательности

Comment: Вариант хороший, но хотелось бы как-то покороче.

Comment: @Qwertiy, боюсь, кроме как опуская прилагательное `экранирующие|экранированные` (по аналогии с `управляющие последовательности`), покороче перевод не сделать.